# List All private IP except few tag names from awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How to get list of all private Ip's of AWS instances except few tags from AWS CLI?

I can get all IP from below command

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[][PrivateIpAddress]"`

I want to exclude IP's from tag "webinstance" & "frontendinstances"
How to use filter for this.

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:stack-name,Values=webinstance" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress]'`

From above I get Ip's related to that specific tag, but dont know how to exclude it.

Comment: Sounds like this is best done via a program rather than using the AWS CLI. For example, a Python script can make calls and then filter the results based on desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EC2 Describe Instances API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) does not support exclusions in filters.

You might be able to achieve the result using some bash scripts using below approach:

- List A: Query all the instances you want.
- List B: Query the instances you want to exclude
- Use [grep: -v - Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373958/how-do-i-remove-matching-lines-from-one-text-file-using-another) to exclude the items from List B.